# How to make optional key in model class in retrofit

Tags: android

In one condition I need to pass `param1` in request and in another condition I need to remove `param1` key itself from the request in Retrofit. How can I do this?

below is the request object

```
class Request {
    @SerializedName("param1")
    @Expose
    var param1: String? = null
    
    @SerializedName("param2")
    @Expose
    var param2: String? = null
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove? Can't you simply pass null?

Comment: @Sarah this is a mandatory param if pass null then api return error msg . so need to remove key itself

Comment: So API returns error when you pass null but works fine when you remove the whole key?